# C++ Program doesn't terminate because of memcpy

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm currently testing memcpy function. I've checked documentation and everything applies when I don't dynamically allocate memory. But when I do, the program just doesn't terminate. Like it enters infinite loop.

Here's the code, I can't get to the point of understanding why it happens because everything seems okay.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct tStudent{
    int indexNo;
    char nameSurname[30];
    int year;
};

int main(){
    tStudent *student=new tStudent;;
    student->indexNo=30500;
    strcpy(student->nameSurname,"Ralph Martinson");
    student->year=2016;

    tStudent *newStudent=new tStudent;
    memcpy(&newStudent, &student,sizeof(tStudent));

    cout<<"PRINT:\n";
    cout<<newStudent->indexNo<<endl;
    cout<<newStudent->nameSurname<<endl;
    cout<<newStudent->year<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Runs fine for me. What compiler are you using?

By the way, you should get in the habit of releasing new'd objects even if the program is only 20 lines.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing with MinGW. In the debugger, it seg faults on the memcpy().

Comment: Its the arguments to memcpy. those shouldn't be addresses of pointers; they should be just the pointers themselves. `memcpy(newStudent, student,sizeof(tStudent));`. And for that matter, `*newStudent = *student;` should be the chosen alternative (eliminating all dynamic memory notwithstanding).

Comment: `memcpy` is *rarely* something you want to use in a C++ program. It doesn't handle constructors nor destructors, so for anything but POD types it's going to be a bug.

Comment: `&newstudent` `&student`  Why are you passing the address of a pointer?

Comment: You may want to revisit pointers: `memcpy(&newStudent, ...)` doesn’t copy the memory where you hope you’d copy it. Of course, you may want to use C++ classes anyway: I find that I hardly ever use `memcpy()` in my code.

Comment: Alright, alright, got it. I shouldn't pass & because I've already declared a pointer here. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `memcpy` you need to pass it two pointers, and the size of the object to copy.  The pointer should be pointer to the object to copy and the object to copy to.  In

```
memcpy(&newStudent, &student,sizeof(tStudent));
```

You don't do that.  Instead you give it pointers to pointers to the objects.  Since `sizeof(tStudent)` is larger than the size of a pointer you are going to start copying into memory you don't own (beacuse you are copy the value of the pointers, not what they point to) which is undefined behavior and can/will cause the program to do strange things.

The proper way to call `memcpy` here is to use

```
memcpy(newStudent, student,sizeof(tStudent));
```

That said, there is no reason to use pointers at all.  Your entire code could be simplified to

```
int main(){
    tStudent student; // don't use a pointer.  Instead have a value object
    student.indexNo=30500;
    strcpy(student.nameSurname,"Ralph Martinson");
    student.year=2016;

    tStudent newStudent = student; // copy initialize newStudent.  You get this for free from the compiler

    cout<<"PRINT:\n";
    cout<<newStudent->indexNo<<endl;
    cout<<newStudent->nameSurname<<endl;
    cout<<newStudent->year<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```